# how to make screen always awake in lua corona?

Tags: android, coronasdk

I use Corona for my game, but when I build into my Android smartphone there is a problem that the screen does not stay on (goes to sleep). My question is how to make the screen stay on having to interact with screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`system.setIdleTimer()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/setIdleTimer.html) to control the idle timer.

> Controls whether the idle timer is enabled. If set to true, the timer will be active (default) or inactive if false. When active, the idle timer dims the screen and eventually puts the device to sleep when no user activity occurs (e.g. screen touches).

Example:

```lua
system.setIdleTimer(false) -- Screen does not turn off automatically
system.setIdleTimer(true)  -- Screen turns off automatically
```